# Prove $(x+y)^a\leq x^a+y^a$ if $0<a\leq1$ and $x,y\geq0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

Prove $(x+y)^a\leq x^a+y^a$ if $0<a\leq1$ and $x,y\geq0$

I need to prove this step for a bigger question. It should be quite basic but I just have no idea...

Comment: If $x+y = 0$, it's clear. Otherwise divide by $(x+y)^a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^{a}$. We may assume $y\ge x$. The line $y=L(x)$ joining $(0, 0)$ and $(y, f(y))$ satisfies the following
$$
f(x)+f(y)\ge L(x)+L(y)=L(x+y)\ge f(x+y),
$$
since $f$ is concave.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is trivial if $x=0$ or $y=0$, so assume neither are $0$.

For $z\ge0$, consider
$$
f(z)=(1+z)^a-z^a\tag{1}
$$
Note that $f(0)=1$. Furthermore, since $a-1\le0$,
$$
\begin{align}
f'(z)
&=a\left((1+z)^{a-1}-z^{a-1}\right)\\
&\le0\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, for $z\ge0$ and $0\lt a\le1$
$$
(1+z)^a-z^a\le1\tag{3}
$$
Set $z=y/x$ and multiply $(3)$ by $x^a$ to get
$$
(x+y)^a\le x^a+y^a\tag{4}
$$